# Issue parsing arabic characters using java

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, arabic

I'm trying to migrate and parse a database to a new schema using Java. 
Problem is there are some characters, specially arab, which get messed up while treating the data in Java.

Here's one of the lines where I'm getting trouble with which is in `countryToParse.sql` file:

`(4, 'Afganistán', 1, 'Afgano', 'Afghanistan', 'AF', 'أفغانستان', 'Afghan', 'أفغاني');`

After I parse it, the resulting line in countryParsed.sql is seen as:

`(4, 'Afganistán', 1, 'Afgano', 'Afghanistan', 'AF', 'أ�?غانستان', 'Afghan', 'أ�?غاني');`

You see how there are certain arabic characters that get messed up.
If I open the files I can check they are both coded in UTF-8.

Here's the Java code I'm using. In method `writeToTextFile()` I've added three ways I found to write a file using UTF-8 (not to mention I'm getting the same error using them three ways)

```
public class MainStackOverflow {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String countryStr = new         String(readTextFile("src/data/countryToParse.sql").getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    writeToTextFile("src/data/countryParsed.sql", countryStr);
}

    public static String readTextFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
        return content;
    }

    public static void writeToTextFile(String fileName, String content) throws IOException {

         /* Way 1 */
         Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), content.getBytes("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);


        /* Way 2 */
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));
            try {
                out.write(content);
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }

        /* Way 3 */
        PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(new File(fileName), "UTF-8");
        out1.write(content);
        out1.flush();
        out1.close();
    /* */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set the encoding in this line:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
```

Try simply this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String countryStr = new String(readTextFile("src/data/countryToParse.sql"), "UTF-8");
    writeToTextFile("src/data/countryParsed.sql", countryStr);
}

public static byte[] readTextFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
}
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you Nicolas

Comment: @miguels Good News !